# Android Support Library rev 23.2 and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: Left is at 23.1.1 and right is at 23.2.0] Updated to Android Support Library rev 23.2 and it added full screen spaces to RecyclerView between each item. Has anybody experienced this issue?

Comment: You may wish to upload a screenshot somewhere and link to it from your question, along with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Does it work fine if you switch back to 22.~? if yes, you should consider filing a bug report - also: Do you use a custom layout manager?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I reverted back to 23.1.1 and it all works as advertised. Where do I fill out a bug report?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This occurs when your RecyclerView rows have their size set to `match_parent` in the scrolling direction.

For example, if a RecyclerView with a vertical `LinearLayoutManager` has the following layout for each row, that row will now actually match the parent's height now. Before version 23.2.0 it would still simply wrap the content.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In this case, changing the height to `wrap_content` will resolve the issue.

This issue is mentioned briefly in [the announcement blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html):

> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of
>   your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as
>   MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

Comment: is there a way to disable it?

Comment: No. This is a change to how LayoutManagers work. The fix of simply switching to `wrap_content` is fairly simple though, as it will provide the same behavior that you had with `match_parent` (which was ignored anyway).

Comment: not in all cases, for example my items are squareImageViews (override onMeasure) and I want them to extend to fill the recyclerView width based on the column number. In this case the wrap_content doesnt work. I have to set a dummy value for the height of each item as a hack...

Comment: Ah, I may have been wrong- try calling `setAutoMeasureEnabled(false)` on your LayoutManager. If that doesn't work, you may need to write your own LayoutManager to handle you use case.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, doesn't change the result

Comment: Ya same here change RecyclerView to wrap_content and got same results. Still working with it though.

Comment: Ok got it to all work! As you can see in my left pic there is three different lists and i had to break them all done and change the heights to wrap_content. Thanks a million!

Comment: I also had to change all my CardView heights to wrap_content.