# Recyclerview increased spacing after upgrade support library to 23.2

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I upgraded support libraries including design, recyclerview, cardview, support, appcompat to 23.2. And the recyclerview items suddenly have huge spacings, as shown at the bottom. I tried all the places, none of them worked, below is part of the code that I found relevant to this:

RecyclerView definition:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reminder_recycler_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Item definition:

```
<com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView
    android:id="@+id/reminder_holder_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    style="@style/CardView.Ripple"/>
```

ViewHolder:

```
public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cardView;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_holder_card_view);
    }
}
```

[image: Huge Spacing 1]

[image: Huge Spacing 2]

And the bounds don't have any problems (the center pieces are in the background, not the same thing):

[image: With bounds]

Comment: Is that the full item definition? As per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638638/android-support-library-rev-23-2-and-recyclerview/35638900#35638900), `match_parent` will do this with a LinearLayoutManager now.

Comment: Ah, I missed the Relative layout, thank you so much......