# Recycler view item fill up entire recycler view height after upgrading support library from "23.1.1" to "23.2.1"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-support-design

Previously, I'm using the following old support libraries "23.1.1".

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

It works pretty well. Here's how my `RecyclerView` looks like

[image]

Now, I wish to migrate to "23.2.1", due to some bug fixes done.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

However, suddenly, all my `RecyclerView` items, seem to fill up the `RecyclerView` entire height.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code snippet of my layout file : https://gist.github.com/yccheok/241a0d38d56305a1be24d09b54eb1600

What really puzzle me is that, although I'm using `"wrap_content"` in my recycler view item layout, it doesn't work as expected.

I don't use any custom layout manager for my `RecyclerView`.

From http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html, I realize 23.2.1 makes quite a number of changes on `RecyclerView` this time.

- Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods. (Issue 201856)
- Reduced the lockdown period in which `RecyclerView` does not allow adapter changes while calculating a layout or scroll. (Issue 202046)
- Fixed a crash when calling `notifyItemChanged()` on an item that is out of view. (Issue 202136)
- Fixed a crash that occurs when `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` adds and removes a view in the same measurement pass. (Issue 193958)

What I suspect most is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201856 , as it involves changing **various measure-spec methods**

So far, I try to reproduce the problem with a simple `RecyclerView` project, with 23.2.1 but failed! It doesn't have "item fills up the `RecyclerView` entire height" problem. My guess is that, my simple project doesn't simulate the complex layout structure of my production project. My production project is having the following layout

```
<Activity>
    <Fragment>
        <View Pager>
            <Fragment>
                <RecyclerView />
            </Fragment>
        </View Pager>
    </Fragment>
</Activity>
```

After debugging for few hours, I'm still cannot find root cause for such problem, any hint?

Thanks.

### What I had tried

I had tried to change `RecyclerView`

from

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

It looks good initially. However, when you perform scrolling, thing doesn't work as expected : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2EChFn6WkI

### UPDATE: I finally figure out the root cause

Is mistake at my side! Since I need to have different margin for the last row item, here's my adapter code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final List<TransactionSummary> transactionSummaries = buyArray.transactionSummaries;

    if (position == transactionSummaries.size() - 1) {
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(lastLayoutParams);
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(normalLayoutParams);
    }
```

Unfortunately, `lastLayoutParams` and `normalLayoutParams` is being initialized as

```
    normalLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    lastLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
```

Using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` solve the problem.

Comment: Did you set the `minHeight` or `maxHeight` or your view item?

Comment: @patwanjau But, I don't know what should be the value of `minHeight` and `maxHeight`.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I'm facing this as well.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I fixed the problem by changing layout height to "wrap_content" from "match_parent"

Comment: As u can see my layout file, I'm also using `wrap_content`. Any idea why it still happen?

Comment: looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638638/android-support-library-rev-23-2-and-recyclerview but apparently not?

Comment: Can you try taking out the stateListAnimator? I've had problems with RecyclerView and Animations before when scrolling.

Comment: I've actually set up a RecyclerView with your XML structure (changing just the color/background parameters), with Activity -> ViewPager -> Fragment -> RecyclerView and it works as expected in 23.2.1. Attach your adapter code

Comment: @tjeubaoit do you mind to share your code? So that I can compare against mine. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly to do with how you are setting the UI in your `onBindViewHolder` function. That is why the error appears when you scroll down, and then the error sticks when you scroll back up. Share your Adapter code so we can determine the error.

Comment: Thanks @Knossos you had made a correct prediction :)

Comment: @Cheok Yan Cheng, Thank you for such a detailed question. BTW, it is a very nice app. Is it opensource by any chance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update

It appears that you are updating the `LayoutParam` for your `View` in your `Adapter`.

It is possible to tell this because your UI appears absolutely fine until you begin scrolling. This means that your XML is correct as it is defined in your XML layout file.

The fact that it changes after scrolling begins, means there is a logic error in your `onBindViewHolder` implementation. That is why the error appears when you scroll down, and then the error sticks when you scroll back up.

### Old answer

Your issue is that your divider has gone rogue:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioSeperatorBackground"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

For testing purposes, set it to:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioSeperatorBackground"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

Make sure you change both of them!

Comment: I had changed both to 30dp. But, it doesn't help much - http://i.imgur.com/hl4mKGY.png

Comment: @CheokYanCheng It looks to me like you are changing the LayoutParams in your RecyclerView Adapter. Can you check that? Perhaps post the code. If it works at the start, then the XML is fine. The issue is in dynamic changes in your Adapter.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Can you post your Adapter?

Comment: You are right. Your suggestion trigger me to re-check my adapter code carefully. I do change the `LayoutParams` dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to see you found it!

Comment: @Knossos Even though the suggestion in comments was correct, the answer as stands right now is not the correct answer to the OP's question. Would you mind adding your suggestion in the original answer for future readability?

Comment: @Sevle: Absolutely

Comment: My issue was i was setting the **"row"** layout parent to match_parent, changing it to wrap_content fix the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. It endend up being that the recycler was not the problem. Check that your CardView item measurements translate to something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

If you're not using CardView, ensure that the element you use in your Adapter for the view has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and not `match_parent`.

If that fails to work, you can add another attribute setting the `minHeight` or `maxHeight` for the view item.

Comment: If you look at `buy_portfolio_card_row_layout.xml` (which is layout file for recycler view item) at https://gist.github.com/yccheok/241a0d38d56305a1be24d09b54eb1600 , you will realize I'm already using `wrap_content` for height.

Comment: Did you set the `minHeight` or `maxHeight` or your view item?

Comment: I can confirm this was the problem for me too, which I encountered right yesterday

Comment: @fillobotto Do you have any screen-shot to describe the problem? As with more problem description, we might soon figure out the cause of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have a same issue as mention top. Using lin 23.2.1 fill all port,I have set item height match_parent to wrap_content. Its working for me

Answer (score 8):

**The good news:**

I can pinpoint you to the exact version that changed RecyclerView's behavior: it's not a change in 23.2.1 but rather a change in [23.2.0 (February 2016)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#rev23-2-0). More specifically:

> RecyclerView.LayoutManager no longer ignores some
>   RecyclerView.LayoutParams settings, such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll
>   direction.
>
> Note: These lifted restrictions may cause unexpected behavior in your layouts. Make sure you specify the correct layout parameters.

Indeed if you fire up the 23.2.0 libraries, you will see the same behavior. That behavior can be simplified in your case as:

Now, when you have RecyclerView's children with `android:layout_x="match_parent"`, that will affect RecyclerView's `android:layout_x`, which was not the case in 23.1.1 and earlier versions.

**The bad news:**

Even if I'm 99% sure that this is the reason behind your problem, I still can't see an issue in your code. I've actually set up a RecyclerView with your XML structure (changing just the color/background parameters), with  a LinearLayoutManager and it works as expected in 23.2.1. I can share my implementation if you want to perform a sanity check.

You should double check your adapter implementation/manipulation even if it's far-stretched.

Comment: This was, indeed, the reason behind my problem.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this bug **row_layout** should have height **fixed** or **wrap_content**! I also had this problem and just realized that the height of row_layout was match_parent.

Answer (score 3):

The height of recycle view must be "wrap_content" only. The recycle view will handle height if the size of cell increases.

**buy_portfolio_fragment.xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioListViewBackground"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_tab_layout_height"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the problematic line:

```
<View   android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"    <!--change this to wrap_content-->
            android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioSeperatorBackground"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

There are 2 places in your layout item that has layout_height="match_parent". You should change them both to wrap_content.

Comment: This is when wrap_content being used - http://i.imgur.com/VOMgAvv.png it seems it does more harm than good.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `row_layout` height to `wrap_content`
so it will take only row actual height space to all the items.