# Recyclerview scrolling up usually jumps up to previous item using match_parent in the imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When I scroll up my recyclerview using `match_parent` in the imageview everytime it has an image the scroll bar will automatically jump upper to the previous item.

The same happens when I define a width to the image (400dp) - smaller than it, no problem happens.

any ideas why my recyclerview jump up when it has and image with `match_parent`?

carview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />...
```

recyclerview

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

oncreateviewholder

```
  @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Posts post =  Posts.get(position);
    holder.post = post;

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    //Showing data on the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
    holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code for `onCreateViewHolder` - specifically, the call to create the `View`?

Comment: hi @Cheticamp my onCreateViewHolder? I added it to my post. not sure if it is what you want. if not, please, tell me!

Comment: Try changing the second argument of `inflate` to `null` to see if that corrects the problem. The second argument is used to define layout parameters - see the 
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)). If that works, you can set the layout parameters separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are having an issue with changes to how `RecyclerView` layouts are handled starting with revision 23.2.0.

See the answer from Sevle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382391/recycler-view-item-fill-up-entire-recycler-view-height-after-upgrading-support-l) that references revision 23.2.0 changes to `RecyclerView` [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev23-2-0).

For a fuller explanation, see [this posting](https://medium.com/@gabri.mariotti/recyclerview-23-2-0-and-item-height-15b08eb06573#.1nivx7dca).

It's all very confusing, but I hope this helps.